# How to run function after plugin installed?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

How can I run a function when my plugin is installed? I tried SafeUp in migrations but it doesn't work.

Comment: You tried making an [Install migration](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/migrations.html#plugin-install-migrations)?

Answer (score 3):

There's an event you can listen to:

```php
use craft\events\PluginEvent;
use craft\services\Plugins;

        // Handler: EVENT_AFTER_INSTALL_PLUGIN
        Event::on(
            Plugins::class,
            Plugins::EVENT_AFTER_INSTALL_PLUGIN,
            function (PluginEvent $event) {
                if ($event->plugin === $this) {
                    // Do stuff here, we were just installed
                }
            }
        );
```

If you generate your plugin scaffolding via [pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/) it will generate the above event for you in your base plugin.